# Order of call when two or more plugin implement same extension point

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

If I have two or more plugin with implementing same extension point like `BuildWrapper` then which order the execute.

Answer (score 0):

The **ordinal** attribute of the *Extension* class.

> Also, by default 'ordinal' is 0, and publishers are sorted in descending order of ordinals, then all publishers without the ordinal defined will be at 0. Will I have to go in and modify the source code of all my publishers to add the 'ordinal'?
>
> The trick is to specify a negative value if you want something way at
> the bottom.

([Source](http://jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com/Hudson-publishers-execution-order-query-tp388801p2719362.html))